# Connecting to my remote site using git bash shell SSH

Tags: ssh, git-bash, ssh-keys, mingw-w64

I can connect using these credentials through ftp but not through ssh.

```
Timothy@ement MINGW64 ~
$ ssh timothy@mywebsite.com
ssh: connect to host mywebsite.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

I'm sure this question has been asked a million times before. Does it have anything to do with ssh keys?

I'm using siteground and in the ssh/shell access area i've added this:

t r timothy@mywebsite.com   KtV/T4QvP4K9n7Zki9n+ZWp6    0.0.0.0/0 - ALL Remove Key | Add IP | Private Key

any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have anything to do with ssh keys?

Yes: see the official [SiteGround](https://www.siteground.com/) documentation [How to use SSH](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/).

- you need to [enable ssh access](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_cpanel.htm) and register your public ssh key.
- then you can use ssh (provided in your `<path-to-git>/usr/bin`) in order to access

  ```
  ssh -p18765 <user>@yourdomain
  ```

SiteGround chooses to run its `sshd` on port 18765, not the default 22.

Answer (score 0):

The siteground tutorials are junk, two out of the three chat support staff I spoke with just referred me to the tutorials when I was attempting to make a connection to my siteground server over ssh.

These are the steps that finally worked: 
From the cPanel Advanced section select SSH/Shell Access

Generate a new key using their utility (make note of the password you used for later use).
*** They have a tutorial that should allow you to create a private key on linux then upload the public key to their site.  That is "not recommended" and I was unable to get that to work.

Once you have their key listed in the current keys table click the Private Key link

Copy the Private Key to a file in your local .ssh directory (make sure the mask is 0600)

run the following command: 
ssh-add 
enter the passphrase you used when generating the key using their utility

If you get a response "Identity added: ..." you are all set

you should now be able to use the command: 
ssh @ -p18765

It doesn't look like they have X11 forwarding enabled though so if you use ssh -X you will get:
 X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0